# ¿Como llenar correctamente objetos cuando se tratan de listas en Java?

Tags: java, lista, arraylist, requests, colecciones

Tengo las siguientes clases en Java

```html
public class CodeRequest {

    private User user;
   
   public User getUser(){
    return user;
   }
   
   public void setUser(User value){
    this.user=value;
   }

}



public class User{

      private String id;
      private List<Registro> registro;
   
    public String getId(){
     return id;
    }
   
    public void setId(String value){
     this.id=value;
    }
   
   public List<Registro> getRegistro(){
    if(registro == null){
      registro = new ArrayList<Registro>();
     }
    return this.registro;
  }
 }
 
public class Registro{

      private id;
      private List<PruebaA> pruebaA;
      private List<PruebaB> pruebaB;
   
    public String getId(){
      return id;
     }
   
     public void setId(String value){
      this.id=value;
     }
   
    public List<PruebaA> getPruebaA(){
      if(pruebaA == null){
         pruebaA = new ArrayList<PruebaA>();
      }
      return this.pruebaA;
   }
   
   public List<PruebaB> getPruebaB(){
    if(pruebaB == null){
        pruebaB = new ArrayList<PruebaB>();
    }
  return this.pruebaB;
   }
     
}
 public class PruebaA{
   
   private id;
   private ElementoBase elemento;
   private TipoA tipoA;
   private TipoB tipoB;
 

}
   private TipoA{

 String elemento1;
 String elemento2;


}

public class PruebaB{
  private id;
  private ElementoBasePruebaB elemento;
  private ImagenPrueba imagenPrueba;
  
}
```

Lo que necesito es ir llenando los objetos de tal manera que al mandarlos se hagan con el siguiente orden y puedan llenar lo siguiente:

```html
<codeRequest>
 <user>
  <id>123</id>
  <registro>
   <id>1</id>
   <pruebaA>
    <id>1</id>
    <elementoBase>PRUEBABASE1</elementoBase>
    <tipoA>
     <elemento1>
      <tipo>ABC</tipo>
      <cadena>SFSG34235WF32</cadena>
     </elemento1>
     <elemento2>
      <tipo>DEF</tipo>
      <cadena>DJRT64353GSDG></cadena>
     </elemento2>
    </tipoA>
   </pruebaA>
   <pruebaB>
    <id>2</id>
    <elementoBasePruebaB>PRUEBABASE2</elementoBasePruebaB>
    <imagenPrueba>
     <imagen>
      <formato>JPG</formato>
     </imagen>
    </imagenPrueba>
   </pruebaB>
  </registro>
 </user>
</codeRequest>
```

y en mi codigo pues tengo lo siguiente

```html
final CodeRequest code = new CodeRequest();
User user = new User();
user.setId(123);
code.setUser(user);
Registro regis =  new Registro();
regis.setId(1);
```

pero no se como hacer para llenar cuando es lista por Ejemplo en **Registro**  como indico que llenare las dos listas **PruebaA** y **PruebaB** como en mi ejemplo. o si fuera solo una de ellas como seria?

y por ejemplo dentro de mi **PruebaA** como lleno que utilizare el objeto tipoA
No se como ir llenando los demas objetos asi como viene en mi ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una abstracción fiel al árbol de nodos debes agruparlos según su jerarquía. Del xml se puede ver lo siguiente:

- `CodeRequest` tiene un `User`.
- `User` tiene `id` y `Registro`.
- `Registro` tiene `id` y 2 `Prueba`s (sería conveniente tener una lista de `Prueba`s).
- `Prueba` tiene `id`, `elementoBase`, `Tipo` e `Imagen`.
- `Tipo` tiene 2 `Elemento`s (sería conveniente tener una lista de `Elemento`s).
- `Elemento` tiene `tipo` y `cadena`.
- `Imagen` tiene `formato`.

Los atributos que se componen de varios atributos terminan siendo clases. Los atributos como `id`, `elementoBase`, el `tipo` de elemento (diferente al tipo de prueba) y `cadena` terminan siendo datos de tipo primitivo.

La abstracción de lo anterior en código sería algo así:

```
class CodeRequest {
    private User user;

    ...
}

class User {
    private int id;
    private Registro registro;

    ...
}

class Registro {
    private int id;
    private Prueba prueba;

    ...
}

class Prueba {
    private int id;
    private String elementoBase;
    private Tipo tipo;
    private Imagen imagen;

    ...
}

class Tipo {
    private List<Elemento> elementos;

    ...
}

class Elemento {
    private String tipo;
    private String cadena;

    ...
}

class Imagen {
    private String formato;

    ...
}
```

Revisa bien otros ejemplos del xml porque podría pasar que un `CodeRequest` contenga más de un `User` y en ese caso entonces el atributo `User` de la clase `CodeRequest` pasaría a ser `List<User>`. Lo mismo para la clase `User` si contiene más de un `Registro` sería entonces `List<Registro>`. Lo mismo para la clase `Prueba` si contiene más de un `Tipo` sería `List<Tipo>`.

Comment: Esas clases ya estan definidas asi, se crearon a partir de un endpoint

Comment: Solo que no se como ir llenando los objetos cuando son list asi como lo menciono en el ejemplo, gracias. Ojala puedas ayudarme en esa parte

Comment: @Root93 Precisamente tienes ese problema por crear clases diferentes para lo que en realidad debería ser del mismo tipo. Por ejemplo `PruebaA` y `PruebaB` son dos clases diferentes cuando deberían ser del mismo tipo para poderlos agregar a una lista. SI fuese solamente una clase que se llame `Prueba` podrías crear un `List<Prueba>` y meter ambos nodos a la lista.

Comment: no comprendo a que te refieres con que deben ser del mismo tipo :/,  asi se generaron y son diferentes por que contienen atributos diferentes

Comment: esas no las puedo cmbiar como dices, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de que tienes el código:

```
final CodeRequest code = new CodeRequest();
User user = new User();
user.setId(123);
code.setUser(user);
Registro regis =  new Registro();
regis.setId(1);
```

Para ponerle el registro al User haria falta:

```
user.getRegistro().add( regis );
```

La invocación a **getRegistro()** genera la lista y la devuelve (por que al principio estaba nula).

--- EDITADO ---

Ahora bien como la variable regis tiene dos listas si quieres agregar un elemento a su lista de tipo PruebaA puedes hacer:

```
final CodeRequest code = new CodeRequest();
User user = new User();
user.setId(123);
code.setUser(user);
Registro regis =  new Registro();
regis.setId(1);

// agregamos regis a la lista de user
user.getRegistro().add( regis );

PruebaA pruebaA = new PruebaA();

//agregamos la prueba que generamos a prueba A
regis.getPruebaA().add( pruebaA );
```

De esta manea vamos ligando las instancias.

Indícame por favor si con esto resuelvo tu duda.

Comment: ok. pero por ejemplo dentro de Registro van dos listas como se observa en mi ejemplo, si solo quiero llenar una, la de PruebaA, como seria? Tengo que crear una instancia de esa clase y luego setearsela a Registro o como?

Comment: Eh agregado lo que comentas. Sí básicamente generas instancias y agregas a las listas correspondientes.